# How do I return only one row with MAX() aggregate?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT Name, MAX(Population) as Population

FROM County

GROUP BY Name;
```

Question: This just returned 16 rows... I want to return only the ONE county which has the highest population, showing 1 row with with the name of that county and its population,, not the highest population for every county. How do I fix this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have different names for 1 country? If not, then you do not need to use `GROUP BY` and `MAX()`

Answer (score 2):

Order and take first

```
SELECT Name, 
       Population 
FROM County 
ORDER BY Population DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with data (Population, Name) as(
    Select '12345'        ,'c1'  union all
    Select '1234500001'   ,'c2'  union all
    Select '1234500002'   ,'c3'  union all
    Select '12346'        ,'c4'  union all
    Select '1234600001'   ,'c4'  union all
    Select '1234600002'   ,'c4' )
SELECT Name, Population
FROM data
where  Population = (SELECT MAX(Population) FROM data)
;
```